# Regex to get text between final two slashes

Tags: regex

Taking a string with the following three examples...

```
/Services/Research/Consumer-services/Mobile-Services/
/Services/Research/Consumer-services/Fixed-Broadband-and-Multi-Play/
/Services/Research/Consumer-services/Next-Generation-Services/
```

I need to:

a) Strip so I only have the string contained between the two final slashes (ie. "Mobile-Services") ... `/.*/(.*)/` seems to accomplish this, though I don't fully understand ti.

b) Replace dashes in the remaining text with spaces. So, "Mobile-Services" becomes "Mobile Services" and "Fixed-Broadband-and-Multi-Play" becomes "Fixed Broadband and Multi Play"

Thank-you very much.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for that. What language are you using?

Comment: import.io - a data-scraping application, which has built-in support for XPath and regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to capture last part:

```
/([^/]+)/?$
```

And use captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP7pJ6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex for get the last string :

```
/(\w+-\w+)/$
```

The anchor `$` will matches right after the last character in the string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pR6zG2/1)